# What should this coldfusion regular expression look like?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

How can I change this to not remove commas, question marks, and periods?

```
#REReplace(string, '[^0-9A-Za-z`\- <?> ]' ,'', 'ALL')# \
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^]` matches everything that is not `^` mentioned in the group `[]`. So you basically list all characters you do not want to replace.

It's sufficient to have every character only once:

```
REReplace(complaints[col][currentrow], '[^0-9A-Za-z ,.?`\-<>]' ,'', 'ALL')
```

Marginal note: If you move `-` to the end of the group as in `<>-]`, you don't have to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
  REReplace(complaints[col][currentrow], '[^0-9A-Za-z,.?`\- <?> ]' ,'', 'ALL')
```